# JRJC not recognized in project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, jira-rest-api

I'm building a rest client that should hook up with JIRA.
I'm trying to use JRJC (https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC) in my project. I'm using Intellij 15.0.4 and gradle and having trouble using the library as it seems like it's not recognized.

my build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "https://maven.atlassian.com/public/"}
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice-parent:4.0'
    compile 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:4.0'
    compile 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6'
    compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-parent:3.0.0'
}
```

I keep getting this error from Intellij saying that `https://maven.atlassian.com/public/` is an unindexed repository.

When I try to call the classes in the project I can't seem to use the relevant imports. Intellij marks an error and says it cannot resolve the symbols.

I have tried to index the repository (it takes about an 40 minutes but it does not seem to make a difference). I've refreshed, reimported and cleaned the project multiple times and still no go. The installation guide in the link I've added above mentions using the Atlassian Plugin SDK however since I'm not using maven directly I'm not sure how relevant it is for me.

Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time here's what has worked for me.
I've added `https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/` to my repositories list and I've added the following dependencies to my gradle.build:

```
compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:3.0.0'
compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-api:3.0.0'
compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-plugin:3.0.0'
```

My gradle.build file now looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice-parent:4.0'
    compile 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:4.0'
    compile 'com.google.inject.extensions:guice-multibindings:4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6'
    compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-parent:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-api:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-plugin:3.0.0'
}
```